# How would i make a function for it as well which will keep track of the empty values of second argument

Tags: javascript, currying

multiply(10)()()()(12)
This a function call and we have to make a function to multiply 2 numbers

Comment: Any code example?

Answer (score 0):

You can [curry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36314/what-is-currying) the function and leverage [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) and [spreading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_function_calls). If there are no arguments supplied then `(...args)` will be an empty array and `.bind(this, ...args)` will create a function without [partially applying](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind#partially_applied_functions) any values to it.

Once all arguments are satisfied, the function is immediately called.

```js
const curry = f => function(...args) {
  if (f.length - args.length <= 0)
    return f.apply(this, args);
        
  return curry(f.bind(this, ...args));
}

const mul = (a, b) => a * b;
const multiply = curry(mul);

console.log(multiply(10, 12));       // = 120
console.log(multiply(10)(12));       // = 120
console.log(multiply(10)()(12));     // = 120
console.log(multiply(10)()()()(12)); // = 120

const obj = {
  x: 2,
  multiply: curry(function(a, b) {
    return a * b * this.x;
  })
}

console.log(obj.multiply(10)()()()(12)); // = 240
```